# Friend Grouping

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, graph, grouping, cluster-analysis

I am writing a program that fetches the links between friends on facebook and then create friendship groups from these links.

I have got as far as creating the data structure which is something like

```
[
    friend_id:[
        mutual_friend_id,
        mutual_friend_id,
        mutual_friend_id,
        etc...
    ]
]
```

After doing this, I am stuck on working out the groupings of friends. I have seen diagrams such as the following that seem to achieve this. or at least separate the friends into groups. Any suggestions how I may be able to do a similar thing: not visually, but programatically create groups using the mutual friends of a user.

[Annotated Diagram](http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3441/3880706498_a3e30e544f.jpg)
[Another Diagram](http://www.vincos.it/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/nexus-vincos-facebook-network.png)

Comment: I’d say first of all you’d have to __define__ what actually constitutes a “group” of users in your point of view. Are _A_ and _B_ (to be) in a “group” if they have a number of _x_ common friends, or should _A_ and _B_ be in a “group” if they both are friends with _C_ and _D_, but not necessarily with each other – or …? Without __defining__ that first, there can be no definite answers to your question, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

with out commenting on programming one option could be to look at tagged photo data. this might help because then friends in reality through photos are defiantly together. try to make a confidence threshold and experiement with that.

addtionally try to use mutual friends, history of jobs and school as well as places.